# Change case to lowercase in JS text area

Tags: javascript

How do I change the case of a character in a textbox/textarea to lowercase onchange?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script>
function f2(string)
{
string=string.toUpperCase();
alert(string);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Here are my text entry objects:</p>
<form>
<p>
Change the scripting (still using one function) so that the text from the alert is shown in uppercase from the textbox but lowercase from the textarea:<br>
<textarea onchange='f2(this.value);'></textarea>
</p>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HDR8t/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried;

```
function f2(textarea)
{
    string = textarea.value;
    alert(string);
    string = string.toLowerCase();

    textarea.value = string;
}
```

With the modification to the onChange as;

```
<textarea onchange='f2(this);'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`.toLowerCase()`](http://freewebdesigntutorials.com/javaScriptTutorials/jsStringObject/toLowerCaseMethod.htm) method.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the value and assign it back.

```
<textarea onchange='this.value=this.value.toLowerCase();'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because nobody fixed your code

**HTML:**

```
<p>Here are my text entry objects:</p>
<form>
  <p>
    Change the scripting (still using one function) so that the text from the alert is shown in uppercase from the textbox but lowercase from the textarea:<br>
  <textarea></textarea>
</p>
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].addEventListener("change", function () {
    this.value = this.value.toLowerCase(); 
});
```

You want to add a change event handler. Inside the event handler you merely overwrite the value property of the element with the string changed to lowerCase.

I also fixed your in-line javascript in your HTML. It is the devil, avoid it.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/t8t8C/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange='this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();'` to make the text uppercase. Replace `toUpperCase` with `toLowerCase` for the opposite.

If desired, you can use your own function instead of just toUpperCase, passing either just the textarea's value or the entire textarea. For example (value only):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<textarea onchange='this.value = f2(this.value);'></textarea>

// JavaScript
function f2(oldText) {
    var newText = oldText.toUpperCase();
    return newText;
}
```

Or (entire textarea):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<textarea onchange='f3(this);'></textarea>

// JavaScript
function f3(ta) {
    ta.value = ta.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pass `this` and then work on it like a `DOMNode`:

```
<p>Here are my text entry objects:</p>
<form>
 <p>
 Change the scripting (still using one function) so that the text from the alert is shown in uppercase from the textbox but lowercase from the textarea:<br>
  <textarea onchange='f2(this);'></textarea>
 </p>
</form>

function f2(el) {
    el.value = el.value.toLowerCase();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HDR8t/1

Answer (score 0):

### Problem 1

I believe the `onchange` event only gets fired when the `<textarea>` no longer has focus. Instead, you'll want to use the `onkeyup` event.

### Problem 2

You're only passing the string to the function. If you want to change the actual text in the `<textarea>`, you'll need to pass the actual DOM element to your function:

```
<textarea onkeyup="f3(this)"></textarea>
```

### Problem 3

Once you pass the element into your function, you'll need to update its `value` attribute:

```
function f3(elem) {
    elem.value = elem.value.toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: The first is only a problem if you want the change to lower case immediately.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I assumed when they said "onchange" what they actually meant was "onimmediatechange".

Answer (score 0):

Try the `[.toLowerCase()][1]` method.

```
<textarea onchange='this.value=this.value.toLowerCase();'></textarea>
```